# Star Wars references in this drawing

Tags: star-wars, object-identification

[image: composite image of Star wars references arranged to look like Darth Vader's helmet]

What are all the Star Wars references in this drawing by [O'lee Graphiste](http://www.olee-graphiste.com/)?

Comment: ooh, cool! +1 Let me see here...

Comment: I see no easter eggs. There are plenty of references though...

Comment: Are you just wanting all the scenes identified? Or are you looking for specific [easter eggs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_%28media%29)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP wants an ID on each superimposed reference (easter egg) that as a whole, make up Vader. :)

Comment: Put together, the scenes make up the helmet of "Darth Vader," an obscure character originating in *A New Hope*.

Comment: @RogueJedi - Chronologically, he originates from ANH.  In universe, he originates from RotS.  Pedantry.  :)

Comment: What's the source of this image?

Comment: That's a sweet drawing, where did you get that? I want that shirt.

Comment: The original is here: http://www.olee-graphiste.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/starwars_project.jpg

Answer (score 64):

**Here are all the *Star Wars* references that I found in the drawing:**

[image]

---

- Obviously, the main reference is Darth Vader's helmet.
- I'm not sure what the thing next to the Death Star is. It could be Alderaan or possibly Yavin or Yavin IV. Yavin IV seems probable.
- The igloo in the center is probably [Lars moisture farm](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lars_moisture_farm)
- The igloo toward the bottom looks like [Kenobi's hut](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ben_Kenobi%27s_home), or it could simply be Tatooine dwellings like Mos Eisley or something.

Comment: Or it could be Yavin IV. The Death Star is facing the wrong direction to blast it in either case.

Comment: Imaginary giant red circle: Darth Vader.

Comment: Bottom right is the log from ESB - http://a.dilcdn.com/bl/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2015/07/BizarreFacts_05.jpg

Comment: The green bit that you’ve labelled “Dagobah swamp”, doesn’t that look more like Endor, with the little straw-thatched huts on the right being Ewok houses? Or am I misremembering what those actually look like? The thing that connects the hut with the ladder to Darth Vader’s nose (what an odd sentence) definitely looks like a tree-to-tree simple suspension bridge, which I don’t recall seeing on Dagobah. **Edit:** Duh, didn’t see you wrote that on the right. Different colours for the Dagobah and the Endor bits might be a good idea.

Comment: The question mark is [Yavin IV](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27842382#27842382).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I've made it a different color to better differentiate them.

Comment: I only see three X-Wings, not four

Comment: @Kevin I think the fourth is a side on view, top left of the 3 front on ones.

Comment: @TomHart I see it now, side with the wings collapsed is kind of hard to make out. Great catch by RedCaio

Comment: The igloo in the lower left isn't Jabba's Palace, is it?

Comment: I think the `?` in the top left by the death star is Endor maybe? Since thats what the Death Star was orbiting.

Comment: Alternatively, the ? + the Death Star might be a reference of the 2 moons of Tatooine.

Comment: It seems like the picture only references the original trilogy, are you sure the two or three references to the prequels are correct?  Darth Maul's lightsaber, for example, seems like it might actually be two separate lightsabers.

Comment: @Peter Tattooine hade two suns, not two moons.  That could be Alderaan, or Yavin IV.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36289/discussion-on-answer-by-redcaio-star-wars-references-in-this-drawing).

Comment: @MarkRogers Geonosis, Otoh Gunga, Theed, and the battle on Mustafar are all from the prequels, and seem fairly clear.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so

Comment: I can't see the helmet, is this one of those pictures that you need to squint at before it pops out?

Comment: @Gusdor I think it depends how you look at it. If you look at the individual bits you don't see the helmet. Look at the general shape and you should see it.